# Time complexity of printing all paths from root to node

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of printing all paths from root to node.
Basically, I am looking for time complexity of the following algorithm.
Traversal of a tree is O(n), where n is number of nodes.
But, in addition to traversal I also print.
So, its something like O(number of leaves * path from root to leaf).
Worst case of space complexity of number of leaves is O(n).
Worst case space complexity of path length is also O(n).

Thus number of leaves = n, and length of path from root to leaf = n. 
Thus, is time complexity O(n^2) ?

```
public void printPath () {
    doPrint(root, new ArrayList<TreeNode>());
}


private void doPrint(TreeNode node, List<TreeNode> path) {
    if (node == null) return;

    path.add(node);

    if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
        System.out.println("Path from root: " + root.item + " to leaf: " + node.item + " - ");
        for (TreeNode treeNode : path) {
            System.out.print(treeNode.item + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    doPrint(node.left , path);
    doPrint(node.right, path);

    path.remove(path.size() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, traversing the tree will be `O(n)`. If you also print the path at each leaf, then you add a `O(height)` factor for that. This is all clearly bounded above by `O(n^2)` like you said, but if you want to be more exact, you can write it as `O(n + num_leafs * tree_height)`.